# Need a powershell script that will moved folders and files from a location to another location

Tags: powershell, directory

Need a powershell script that will moved folders and files from a location to another location that are older then x number of days but some folders are exempted.

Also needs to have the ability to email a list of files and folders that it moved.

I can move the files in a folder, I'm not sure how to move the entire folders though.

Here is some code I have put together so far, any suggestions would be great

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned

#----- define parameters -----#
#----- get current date ----#
$Now = Get-Date
#----- define amount of days ----#
$Days = "7"
#----- define folder where files are located ----#
$TargetFolder = "C:\test"
$TargetPath = "C:\test5"

#----- define extension ----#
$Extension = "*.*"
#----- define LastWriteTime parameter based on $Days ---#
$LastWrite = $Now.AddDays(-$Days)

#----Exclusion List ----#
$exclude =@('test1', 'test2')


#----- get files based on lastwrite filter and specified folder ---#
$Files = Get-Childitem -path $TargetFolder -Include $Extension -Recurse | Where {$_.LastWriteTime       -le "$LastWrite"}  -and $_Name -ne $exclude | foreach ($_)} #-


foreach ($File in $Files)
    {
    if ($File -ne $NULL)
        {
        write-host "Deleting File $File" -ForegroundColor "DarkRed"
        Move-Item $File.FullName $TargetPath -force
        }
    else
        {
        Write-Host "No more files to delete!" -foregroundcolor "Green"
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you selecting directories based on the files lastwrite time or do you need to look at the lastwritetime of the folder itself regardless of the contents?

Comment: The folder's lastwritetime itself regardless of content would be preferable actually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A shorthand version that is supported on PowerShell v3 or higher. This would find all the folder where the `LastWriteTime` is older that 7 days and move them.

```
$LastWrite = (Get-Date).AddDays(-7)
gci c:\temp -Directory -Recurse | ?{$_.LastWriteTime -le $LastWrite} | select -expand fullname | %{Move-Item $_ $TargetPath}
```

There would be no point with file exclusions if you are just looking at the folder time so that logic is omitted. Same code but easier to read:

```
$LastWrite = (Get-Date).AddDays(-7)
Get-ChildItem $TargetFolder | Where-Object{$_.LastWriteTime -le $LastWrite} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName | ForEach-Object{
    Move-Item $_ $TargetPath
}
```

**Caveat**

There could be an issue where you are trying to move a folder and a parent might have been previously moved. Don't really have the test environment to check that right now. Could just use a little test before the copy just in case.

```
If(Test-Path $_){Move-Item $_ $TargetPath}
```

**Email**

A starting point for working with email would be [Send-MailMessage](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849925.aspx). There are other methods as well.

**Folder Exclusion**

If you wanted to omit certain folders there is a couple of ways to accomplish that. If you know the whole folder name you want to omit you could add this `$exclude =@('test1', 'test2')` like you already have and change the `Where` clause.

```
Where-Object{$_.LastWriteTime -le $LastWrite -and $exclude -notcontains $_.Name}
```

If you didnt know the whole name and maybe that `$exclude` only contained the partial name you could do this as well using a little regex

```
$exclude =@('test1', 'test2')
$exclude = "({0})" -f ($exclude -join "|")

#..... other stuff happens

Where-Object{$_.LastWriteTime -le $LastWrite -and $_.Name -notmatch $exclude}
```

Comment: Thanks, how would I go about adding exceptions for certain folders rather then the files themselves. For instance say I have a folder with 20 subfolders I want to keep, and 20 more I want to move. How would I add an exception list for the folders i don't want to move?

Comment: In the case where the folder may already exist in the destination. is there a way to set it too overwrite it. Currently it will fail if it already exists at it's destination with cannot create file when that file already exists. I know you have include that test If(Test-Path $_){Move-Item $_ $TargetPath} but even if it exists I'd like it to be able to go ahead and overwrite.

Comment: I decided to use copy-item and then remove-item afterwards to cater for this seems to have worked.  Just need to do a bit of further testing

Comment: this is the current code     Get-ChildItem $TargetFolder | Where-Object{$_.LastWriteTime -le $LastWrite -and $exclude -notcontains $_.Name} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName | ForEach-Object{
 write-host "Moving File $_ to $TargetPath on $today" -ForegroundColor "DarkRed" 
 
    Copy-Item $_ $TargetPath -recurse -force
 
 Remove-Item $_ -r -force -confirm:$false

Comment: `Move-Item -Force` should address that like you had in your original code. So does this solution work for you then?

Comment: if I wanted to read in the list of exclusions from a file, what would be the best way to accomplish that and still have that whole get-childitem function to work. Could I use something like this $exclude = Get-Content "c:exceptions.txt"

Comment: Have them in the text file.. one on each line. Then you would have `$exclude = Get-Content c:\path\to\file.txt` @user4432997